# Object History Related List in Lightning Experience

Tags: salesforce, sfdc

I found that Object History related list isn't supported in Lightning Experience : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000LgQWAA0 . I need to show it in Lightning; is there any way to show the Related History on Contact (in lightning) without creating a new object.
 
Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to show Object History related list. Let's up vote this idea.

Comment: I need to track 10-12 fields of contact in Lightning, is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to track few standard and custom field on Contact using Field History Tracking. In lightning, it doesn't seem to show the "Contact History" related list and its history records at all even if you add it to the page layout.

The only way I could do is to switch to "Classic View" and see the field changes in Contact History related list for the contact record.

If you need to see this working in Lightning, We will have to wait till the following idea (https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000LgQWAA0) gets incorporated by Salesforce.

Update:
This has been delivered in Summer 17, for those who are still looking.